# Login with remembering tests not failing

Tags: railstutorial.org

Normally I'd be happy my tests are passing, but not in this case. I'm going through the tutorial again, making my own app. So I have a few differences with the tutorial code, which are (hopefully) just cosmetic. All the logging in and session stuff should be the same.

After slogging through Section 8.4.2 Login With Remembering, the tests are supposed to fail (listing 8.37), because there's no way to log out. But mine pass.

Does anybody know which test is supposed to fail? I don't know how I will track down a problem without a failure.

Comment: Doh! I missed the section on logging out. I was missing these tests:         delete logout_path
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    follow_redirect!
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path     <----- fails

Answer (score 0):

I missed the section on logging out. After adding that code, I get an expected failure in "login with valid information followed by logout"

```
delete logout_path 
assert_not is_logged_in? 
assert_redirected_to root_url f
ollow_redirect! 
assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path <----- fails
```